# How to add records from a list to one2many fields?

Tags: python, arrays, list, range, odoo

I have three fields: start year, end year and range. I need to add the list of ranges of the two second fields into the range field.

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('start', 'end')
def years(self):
    self.rang = [int(x) for x in range(int(self.start),int(self.end))]
    pass

start = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
end = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
rang = fields.One2many(compute=years )
```

I get this error message:

> Sorry, you are not allowed to access this document. Please contact your system administrator if you think this is an error.

(Document model: _unknown) - (Operation: read, User: 2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a **comodel_name** to your **one2many** fields, You can look in the official documentation of Odoo here [enter link description here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.fields.One2many)

Answer (score 0):

base on the question you mentioned, I guess you want to display product produce date between a range.

```py
start = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
end = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
product_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="product_model")

@api.onchange('start','end')
def _search_year_range(self):
    if self.start and self.end:
        model = self.env['product_model']
        # because your info is too less, you need to fix domain base on your case by yourself.
        domain = [('product_date', '>', self.start),('prduct_date', '<', self.end)]
        records = model.search(domain)
        self.product_ids = [(6, 0, records.ids)]
```

Comment: thanks dear for your answer, but i don't need the product_date  field 
i just need the range between the two fields start, end to be in many2many field 
i'll be happy if you help mo on it

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a `Selection` field instead of `One2many`.
Try out this ,

```
@api.depends('start', 'end')
def _years(self):
  if self.start and self.end:
     return list([(str(x), int(x)) for x in range(int(self.start),int(self.end))])

start = fields.Char(string="", required=False)
end = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
rang = fields.Selection(_years )
```